# Can LightSwitch scaffold all the screens from the selected database tables?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, scaffolding, lightswitch-2013

LightSwitch provides a great interface for generating simple data management screens one at a time. Are there any tools that will generate all the screens for all the tables I select in one hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options. If you're using VS2012 or earlier you could use Aide by xpert360.com or if you're using VS2013 the March update has options for new projects to scaffold all the main screens for your entities. If you load an old project created prior to March update you will have to update it before the scaffolding option becomes available. Once the update is installed you will see the common screens option when creating a new screen.